# WooCommerce Bookings Calendar Always Visible Mode: Add product add-on selection on Booked Dates

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I am using WooCommerce Bookings and on Single Product page, I have the option Always Calendar display enabled which displays a full-width calendar on the product page.

For a booked order, I am trying to add the reservation type that is selected using Product Add-ons. The are namely Regular Reservation, Last-Minute Reservation and Single Reservation.

I have attached a screenshot showing what I am trying to achieve on the booked dates cell.

[image: Calendar]

I tried using the hook add_filter( 'wc_bookings_get_time_slots_html', 'filter_bookings_get_time_slots_html_callback', 10, 6 ); to display but nothing happens. I even tried to display a simple text like below to see if it works but nothing displays

`add_filter( 'wc_bookings_get_time_slots_html', 'filter_bookings_get_time_slots_html_callback', 10, 6 );
function filter_bookings_get_time_slots_html_callback( $block_html, $blocks ) {
$block_html = 'Hi, You can see me';

```
return $block_html;
```

}`

So I am not sure what hook to use to display text on the booked date cells.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks